# Zend framework how to set barcode height and width?

Tags: codeigniter, zend-framework, width, barcode

```
   $CI=& get_instance();    
   $CI->load->library('zend');
   $CI->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
   $barcode_image_name = "123456789000";


    $barcodeOptions = array(
            'text' => "123456789000", 
            'barHeight'=> 100,
            'factor'=>4,

    );


   $file = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', $barcodeOptions, array());

   $store_image = imagepng($file,FCPATH."uploads/barcodeImage/{$barcode_image_name}.png");
   return $store_image;
```

This the code where i load the xend library in Codeigniter Frameword now i want to set the Width and height of barcode...

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112386/zend-barcode-is-not-rendered-in-codeigniter/40117609#40117609

Comment: brother my barcode is rendered but i want to set custom height and width of that barcode...

Answer (score 0):

The width of the barcode is defined by the barcodeParams `barHeight` and `factor`. There is no option of setting the width manually.

Source: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.barcode.objects.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CSS to set the height and width of generated barcode image.

```
<img class='barcode-image' 
     src='" . site_url() . "controllers/function_setbarcode/" . $your_code . "' 
     alt='Barcode' />
```

And I have to set height and width

```
img.barcode-image {
    width: auto;
    height: 65%;
}
```