# How to generate barcode in PDF using zend library in codeigniter 3.x

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

i am using **zend library** to generate `barcode` how to generate barcode with heading. below is my code

```
public function barcode($visitor_id) {
        $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
        Zend_Barcode::render('code39', 'image', array('text' => $visitor_id, 'drawText' => TRUE), array());
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... And what's a problem ?

Comment: i want to change this to pdf how to do it

Comment: $pdf = new Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Pdf();
  $barcodeOptions = array(
   'text' => '11111',
  );
  $rendererOptions = array(
   'topOffset' => 50,
   'leftOffset' => 50,
  );
  Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf',
   $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf)->draw();

Comment: tried this above but not working

Comment: am getting this error An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'Zend_Pdf' not found

Filename: /var/www/html/poswift-reynolds-ui/application/controllers/Item.php

Line Number: 408

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/poswift-reynolds-ui/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: So it means that something is wrong with your autoloader, and unable to load Zend_Barcode class. If you are using composer check configuration, if not, add require_once('path/to/class/Zend/Barcode.php') file at the top your index.php or something.

Comment: Zend_Barcode is loading when i try to generate barcode as image its working fine when ever i try to generate it as pdf am getting this error

Comment: It's still autoloading problem. Zend expect that you provide autoloader which can resolve Zend_Pdf do path. I'm sure you don't have that configured class. Try to load Zend_Pdf before Zend_Barcode (require or something). It should resolve your problem, but im not sure if another required file wil be problem. Read this article: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html.

Comment: So what do you suggest

Comment: In your application bootstrap file add these lines:
require_once('path/to/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setZfPath('path/to/zf', 'your_ZF_version'); or write your own autoloader which can resolve this files and configure it in your bootstrap application file.

Comment: @AkshayKH This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112386/zend-barcode-is-not-rendered-in-codeigniter/40117609#40117609

Comment: @wolfgang1983 its working for image. But not working for PDF code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a pdf file such as viewpdf.php using mpdf and call the barcode function in  tag.

**create viewpdf.php in view folder**

```
  <?php
 $code= KD12345;

include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$html='<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .container{width: 1450px; padding-bottom:2px;}
    body, table {
        /* to centre page on screen*/
        margin:0 auto;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:2%;">
           <img class="img-responsive" style="text-align:center;" src="'. base_url().'index.php/Controller/barcode?bcd='.$code.'" alt="">
        </div> 
</body>
</html>';

$mpdf=new mPDF('', 'A4', 0, '', 2, 2,5, 0, 0, 0);
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($code.'.PDF','I');
exit;
?>
```

**In controller folder Controller.php write a following function to display viewpdf.php**

```
public function ViewPdf()
    {   
        $this->load->view("viewpdf.php");
    }
```

**and another function for generate barcode**

```
public function barcode()
    {
        $code=$_GET['bcd'];
        $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

        $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $code);
        $rendererOptions = array('imageType'=>'png');
        Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();

    }
```