# I am having trouble to use zend(ZF V 1.12.3) barcode library in CodeIgniter(V 3.1.7)

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, codeigniter-3, barcode

I have done everything according to the the following rule.

> 1)Download Zend Framework from the official website
>
> 2)Unzip the Zend Framework package, and copy the Zend folder (under Library) to your CodeIgniter installation’s application/libraries/

Then I have created a new php file nammed Zend.php under application/libraries  with the following code.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {exit('No direct script access allowed');}
 
/**
 * Zend Framework Loader
 *
 * Put the 'Zend' folder (unpacked from the Zend Framework package, under 'Library')
 * in CI installation's 'application/libraries' folder
 * You can put it elsewhere but remember to alter the script accordingly
 *
 * Usage:
 *   1) $this->load->library('zend', 'Zend/Package/Name');
 *   or
 *   2) $this->load->library('zend');
 *      then $this->zend->load('Zend/Package/Name');
 *
 * * the second usage is useful for autoloading the Zend Framework library
 * * Zend/Package/Name does not need the '.php' at the end
 */
class CI_Zend
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   string $class class name
     */
    function __construct($class = NULL)
    {
        // include path for Zend Framework
        // alter it accordingly if you have put the 'Zend' folder elsewhere
        ini_set('include_path',
        ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH . 'libraries');
 
        if ($class)
        {
            require_once (string) $class . EXT;
            log_message('debug', "Zend Class $class Loaded");
        }
        else
        {
            log_message('debug', "Zend Class Initialized");
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * Zend Class Loader
     *
     * @param   string $class class name
     */
    function load($class)
    {
        require_once (string) $class . EXT;
        log_message('debug', "Zend Class $class Loaded");
    }
}
```

I hope that this is the actual way to install zend framework in CodeIgniter.
Then in my controller on a function I have written this following code to generate barcode.

```
public function product($product_id){
        $pid = filter($product_id);
        if($this->product_model->check_product_by_id($pid)){
            $barcode = $pid;
            $this->load->library('zend');
            $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
            Zend_Barcode::render('code39', 'image', array('text' => $visitor_id), array());
            $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$barcode), array())->draw();
            imagepng($imageResource);
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid product parameter');
            redirect('products/all');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

But this is showing the following error

[image: zend library loading error]

I have tried all the way available on the web including Stackoverflow. But nothing helped me out of this problem. Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: I see you have `class CI_Zend {}` try with out CI like `class Zend {}`

Comment: Also this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112386/zend-barcode-is-not-rendered-in-codeigniter/40117609#40117609

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Let me try it.