# Generate Barcode Using Zend_Barcode, not print in PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

Code For generate Barcode

```
Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=> $code), array());
```

Barcode generated successfully.

HTML code for generate BARCODE

```
site_url().'/employees_card/barcode/'.$employee_detail['nic']
```

PDF Code is

```
       $html = $this->load->view('employees/view_backcard', $data,TRUE);
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
        $dompdf->setPaper('Legal', 'Landscape');
        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();
        // Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
        $dompdf->stream("codex",array("Attachment"=>1));
```

Then i want to print it through DomPdf, HTML preview for code is https://prnt.sc/jrrzdr

But final PDF didn't load barcode , please any solution?

Comment: Where is the PDF code? Are you getting an error?

Comment: not receiving any error, for details please found the attach image file https://prnt.sc/jrt5aj url

Comment: This has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112386/zend-barcode-is-not-rendered-in-codeigniter

Comment: no, my question is different , want to generate PDF using dompdf and print this barcode to PDF. Barcode already generated but not print on the PDF.
but my problem is solved, by using HTMLTOCANVAS library, convert HTML to image and render it to PDF file. Thanks dear